# Extra character at the end of binary file output

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int data[4] = { 2, 4, 8, 16 };
  
  std::fstream out_file = std::fstream("my_file.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      out_file.write((char*) &data[i], 4);
  }
  
  out_file.close();
}
```

Which outputs:

```
 clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
 ./main
 od my_file.dat 
0000000 000002 000000 000004 000000 000010 000000 000020 000000
0000020

```

Note that there's an extra "0000020" at the end of the binary file. Why is this? How do I get rid of it? I think this is a carriage return character? But I'm not writing a string...

Comment: It is file offset printed by `od`.

Comment: but there shouldn't be an address at 0000020 right?

Comment: Use: `od -t x1 my_file.dat`.  You'll notice that there is no data at `0000020`, it's only there to note there is no more data there.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to call `out_file.close();` at the end of `main()`. The destructor will do that.